# Does "make something of a meal out of [something]" mean essentially "make a meal of [something]"?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I have found in a dictionary the meanings of the idiom "make a meal (out) of something":

> **P5.** to make a (also †one's) meal of:
>   **a.** To consume as a meal, to devour; (in extended use) to take advantage of, exploit, ravage, etc.
>   **b.** *fig.* To treat with undue fuss or attention, esp. for effect; to make (a task, etc.) unduly laborious.

["make, v.1". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112645?rskey=KbJCp2&result=2&isAdvanced=true (accessed March 11, 2016).]

What I would like to know is whether I understand correctly that the inserted expression "something of a" does not modify the meaning of the original substantially, i.e., it only weakens the original idiom.

I want to be certain that I correctly understand this sentence:

> Indeed, one way to sum up Mackie's argument [...] is to say that Russell **made something of a meal out of 2+2=4.**

(*Mathematics, Education and Philosophy: An International Perspective*, 1994, edited by Paul Ernest, p.30.)

Comment: Did you either look up the idiom "make a meal of" in a dictionary, or at the least, Google it?  If so, what did you find?

Comment: Gah, I forgot to ask about prior research. Deleted my answer.

Comment: C'mon guys! No need to make a meal of it! Just close the question and move on.

Comment: The poster is confused because two expressions are being used together, and all he gets is downvotes and a closed question? How is he supposed to research a phrase that doesn't exist? This is becoming a very hostile site... Voting to reopen because I am wiling to explain that his example is not a single phrase.

Comment: @RoaringFish In both the title of the question and its very  first paragraph, OP has clearly identified "*make a meal of <something>*" as the phrase which is confusing him, and has furthermore correctly labelled it an idiom. The obvious next step is to look up the meaning of that specific idiom in the general reference tool which is dedicated to recording and reporting the meanings of idioms: to wit, the  dictionary. If he does that and is still confused, he can come back, edit his question to clarify what questions were not answered by the dictionary, and I will also vote to reopen.

Comment: @DanBron ~ neither the title nor the first paragraph say "make a meal out of something". They both say "make *something* of a meal out of something", and that is the phrase he incorrectly labels as an idiom. It is hardly suprising he finds that phrase difficult to decode as it is an amalgam of two expressions.

Comment: @RoaringFish If you're right that it's an inability to analyze the phrase and identify its components, then my strong sense is OP would be better served by being directed (i.e. having his question stay closed here and migrated) to ELL. We do not address questions which are already expertly answered by a dictionary, or would be immediately obvious to the man on the street (a native speaker). That can create an air of unfriendliness, I know, but the trade-off of accepting such questions is even worse.

Comment: @RoaringFish I was just chatting about this and was prompted to post a [suggestion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7795/142322) on meta.

Comment: What I have found in dictionary is "make a meal (out) of something". What I would like to know whether I understand correctly that the inserted expression "something of a" does not modify the meaning of the original substantially, i.e., it is is only weakens the original idiom.

Comment: @GyorgySereny Wonderful! If you [edit] that concern into your question (mention what you found in the dictionary already), we might be able to re-open this question for people to offer answers.

Comment: Well done. I have voted to re-open and upvoted. You only need a couple more votes. By he way, the short answer is your current understanding is correct. The compound phrase is substantially the same as plain "make a meal of something", but slightly weaker.

Comment: @Dan Bro Thank you. I should still learn the working of this site. :-)

Comment: Please provide an example.  It's entirely unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: @ Hot Licks I wanted to be certain that I understand correctly this sentence: "Indeed, one way to sum up Mackie's argument [...] is to say that Russell
made something of a meal out of 2+2=4." (Mathematics, Education and Philosophy: An International Perspective Edited by Paul Ernest, p.30)
@JEL Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two expressions mixed together here, which may be why you are having trouble with it.

One is the *something of a...* expression, which means '[to some extent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/something-of-a/)'. The other is *make a meal of...* which means '[to make something overly complicated](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_a_meal_of)'.